# CLion GLSL Support plugin. Adding file associations

Tags: opengl, glsl, clion

Recently I started [OpenGL tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/).

I use CLion as IDE. But it doesn't have native support of GLSL.

There is a CLion plugin called "GLSL support", which adds `*.shader` file association and shader language syntax highlight, which is pretty handy.

The problem is: in openGL tutorials shader files have extensions `*.vertexshader / *.fragmentshader`, which GLSL support plugin doesn't want to recognize.

Does anyone know how to add file associations for CLion GLSL support plugin? Or CLion extensions in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future visitors, there's an option in the settings.

Navigate to Settings>Editor>File Types>Recognized File Types>OpenGL Shading Language file and then add the necessary file name patterns.
If you don't have that file type, then install the GLSL Support plugin.

Answer (score -2):

GLSL shaders can have any file extension you want, after all, you write the code that loads them!
Quite often I name mine things like `simple.vert`, `simple.frag` or even just use `.txt` if I'm being lazy.

If you want Clion to pick them up just use `.shader`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my question.
The question was: how to get CLion's "GLSL support" plugin to pick up any file extension I want, because it is quite tedious to rename them in all ogl tutorials and then modify CMakeLists for each executable.

Comment: Well it looks like it supports `.glsl`, `.frag`, `.fsh`, `.vert`, `.vsh`, `.tesc`, `.tese`, `.comp`, `.geom` and `.shader`. If you don't want to rename any files then you could build the [plugin from source](https://github.com/Darkyenus/glsl4idea) and change the supported extensions in [this file](https://github.com/Darkyenus/glsl4idea/blob/eb2268bfe279aa9b0627ea0c7ad2412984b52faa/src/glslplugin/GLSLSupportLoader.java). Personally I'd recommend writing all of the tutorial code out instead of just copy/pasting or building the demos, you learn better that way :)